# Iterate through XML nodes with Lua

Tags: regex, xml, lua, pattern-matching

I'm trying to iterate through all the 'FindMe' nodes but I'm struggling with the pattern matching. This is going to be used as a plugin in another piece of software so I'm trying to avoid using a parsing library.

Given the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NodeA>
    <NodeB>
        <FindMe attr="1">
            <NodeC attr="1" />
        </FindMe>
        <FindMe attr="2">
            <NodeC attr="2" />
        </FindMe>
    </NodeB>
</NodeA>
```

When I try this it only prints the last match

```
for k, _ in src:gmatch(".+(<FindMe .+</FindMe>).+") do
    print(k)
end
```

```
<FindMe attr="2">
    <NodeC attr="2" />
</FindMe>
```

When I try this it prints all the matching nodes as one result

```
for k, _ in src:gmatch('<FindMe.+>.+</FindMe>') do 
    print(k) 
end
```

```
<FindMe attr="1">
    <NodeC attr="1" />
</FindMe>
<FindMe attr="2">
    <NodeC attr="2" />
</FindMe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.-` instead of `.+`, such that `gmatch('<FindMe.+>.+</FindMe>')` becomes `gmatch('<FindMe.->.-</FindMe>')`. Using `-` implies non-greedy search, so it gets the smallest possible number of characters until the match (instead of the largest possible number of characters until the match with the greedy search). You can also use `gmatch('<FindMe[^>]+>.-</FindMe>')`, which should have the same effect.

Comment: It does not work in case `<FindMe>...<FindMe>... </FindMe> </FindMe>`

Comment: @moteus in such cases you must implement some sort of parser, as your syntax is not straightforward anymore

Comment: @moteus, correct, but it wasn't in the assignment and would require more complex processing, as Darius suggested.