# Parsing text file - Lua

Tags: lua

I have a text file contains:

```
<Response>
    <IP>17.178.96.59</IP>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <RegionCode></RegionCode>
    <RegionName></RegionName>
    <City>Chicago</City>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
    <TimeZone>America/Chicago</TimeZone>
    <Latitude>37.751</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-97.822</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>0</MetroCode>
</Response>
```

How to remove each  and  so I get only:

17.178.96.59,
US,
United States,
nil,
nil,
Chicago,
nil,
America/Chicago,
37.751,
-97.822,
0

Using the Lua script.

Comment: `answer:gsub("><",">nil<"):gsub("<.->",""):gsub("%c%s+",","):sub(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what you already tried, but there is a recently discussed [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751245/iterate-through-xml-nodes-with-lua/) on how to iterate over XML nodes that should work well for your purposes. Just replace fixed element names with something like `[%w_]+` and collect parsed values into a table and you'll get the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am trying to do.

```
int = getInternet()
url3 = 'https://freegeoip.app/xml/17.178.96.59'
result = int.getURL(url3)
result = result:gsub("><",">nil<"):gsub("<.->",""):gsub("%c%s+",","):sub(2)..'nil'

print(result)
-- = 17.178.96.59,US,United States,nil,nil,nil,nil,America/Chicago,37.751,-97.822,0,mil

geoResult = {}

for word in string.gmatch(result, '([^,]+)') do
  --print(word)
  table.insert(geoResult, word)
  --for i,v in ipairs(result) do print(i,v) end
end

print('IP : '..geoResult[1])
print('Country ID : '..geoResult[2])
print('Country Name : '..geoResult[3])
print('Region Code : '..geoResult[4])
print('Region Name : '..geoResult[5])
print('City : '..geoResult[8])
print('ZIP Code : '..geoResult[7])
print('Time Zone : '..geoResult[8])
print('Latitude : '..geoResult[9])
print('Longitude : '..geoResult[10])
print('Metro Code : '..geoResult[11])

-- result:
17.178.96.59,US,United States,nil,nil,nil,nil,America/Chicago,37.751,-97.822,0,nil 

IP : 17.178.96.59 
Country ID : US 
Country Name : United States 
Region Code : nil 
Region Name : nil 
City : America/Chicago 
ZIP Code : nil 
Time Zone : America/Chicago 
Latitude : 37.751 
Longitude : -97.822 
Metro Code : 0
```

Comment: but shortest way to do immediately in table: `t = {};  t.ip = result:match('<IP>(.-)</IP>') ; print(t.ip)` etc.

Comment: Yes, true. But that only prints the IP. I need to get the geolocation results and store them as variables for use on my windows form. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: hmm,  by analogy the other tags